# Compute dimension of span of a subset of dual space using the induced map to euclidean space.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\Phi=\{\phi_1,...,\phi_m\} \subset V^*$ for $V$ a finite dimensional vector space of dimension $n\leq m$ over a field $\mathbb{F}$. I would like to prove the following claim:
$\Phi$ spans $V^*$ if and only if the map $\tilde{\Phi}: V \to \mathbb{F}^m$ given by $v\mapsto (\phi_1(v),...,\phi_m(v))$ has kernel 0/ $\operatorname{im}\tilde{\Phi}$ has dimension $n$. I would very much appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: Asked for anyone? either kernel is trivial or $im\widetilde{\Phi}$ has dimension $n$?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the vector space to be euclidean, applying Riesz Representation Theorem, we can find unique $v_1, v_2, \dots, v_m$ such that

$$\Phi_i : = \langle \cdot, v_i \rangle \qquad 1\leq i \leq m.$$

First assume that $\Phi$ spans $V^*$. Then we can extract a basis of $V^*$ from $\Phi$, say $\{\Phi_1, \Phi_2, \dots, \Phi_n\}$. We claim that $\{v_1, v_2, \dots, v_n\}$ is linearly independent.

Suppose on the contrary that there exists $c_1,c_2, \dots, c_n$ not all zero, such that
$$c_1v_1+c_2v_2+\dots +c_nv_n={\bf 0}.$$
Define $f: V\to \mathbb{F}$ by
$$f(x):=\langle x, c_1v_1+c_2v_2+\dots +c_nv_n \rangle.$$
Then $f$ is identically zero, and we have
$$c_1\Phi_1+c_2\Phi_2+\dots +c_n\Phi_n={\bf 0},$$
a contradiction.

Now, $\widetilde{\Phi}(v)= {\bf 0}$ implies that $\Phi_i(v)=0$ for each $i$, in particular $1\leq i \leq n$. Therefore, $v\perp v_i$ for all $1\leq i \leq n$. Since $dim~V=n$, this shows that $v={\bf 0}$. Thus, $\ker \widetilde{\Phi}= {\bf 0}$.

For the converse, $\Phi_i(v)=0$ for all $1\leq i \leq m$ implies that $v={\bf 0}$. Applying Riesz Representation Theorem, we can find unique $v_1, v_2, \dots, v_m$ such that

$$\Phi_i : = \langle \cdot, v_i \rangle \qquad 1\leq i \leq m.$$
We show that $\{v_1, v_2, \dots, v_m\}$ contains a basis of $V$. Suppose on the contrary that $\{v_1, v_2, \dots, v_m\}$ does not contain a basis of $V$. Then there exists non-zero $v$ such that $v\perp v_i$ for $1\leq i \leq m$. Therefore, $\Phi_i(v)=0$ for all $1\leq i \leq m$ yet $v\neq{\bf 0}$, a contradiction. From this you can prove that $\{\Phi_1, \Phi_2, \dots, \Phi_m\}$ contains a basis of $V^*$.

Comment: Thank you! I would guess that this argument also applies to "orthogonality" in terms of a more general tensor, such as the Killing form for semisimple Lie algebras, which is symmetric and non-degenerate. That's the context from where my question came (:

Comment: Thanyou@DanielRiBR1011101. Exactly.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, $\Phi$ spans $V^*$ if and only if the map $\lambda : \mathbb F^m \to V^*$ given by $$(a_1,\dots,a_m) \mapsto a_1\phi_1 + \cdots + a_m\phi_m$$ is surjective. Now, $\lambda$ is surjective if and only if its dual $\lambda^* : V^{**} \to (\mathbb F^m)^*$ is injective, and if you consider the isomorphisms $\operatorname{ev} : V \to V^{**}$ and $\mu : (\mathbb F^m)^* \to \mathbb F^m$ given by $$v \mapsto (\phi \mapsto \phi(v)) \quad \textrm{and} \quad  f \mapsto (f(e_1),\dots,f(e_m))$$ respectively (where $e_1,\dots,e_m$ is the standard basis for $\mathbb F^m$), it is easy to see that $\lambda^*$ is injective if and only if $\mu \circ \lambda^* \circ \operatorname{ev}$ is injective, but $\mu \circ \lambda^* \circ \operatorname{ev} = \widetilde\Phi$.

Comment: Thank you so much! just the kind of argument I was looking for (: